# CustomTextField (Does get a StackOverFlow error)

Tags: blackberry, customization, textfield

Hi i have typed a code but it doesn't seem to work will you let me know what's the error?

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FocusChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Manager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.BasicEditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.EditField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;


public class CustomTextField extends VerticalFieldManager implements FocusChangeListener{
    private int textWidth=0;
    private Font font=Font.getDefault();
    private int textHeight=0;
    public EditField basicEditField;

    public CustomTextField(int width,int height) {
        textWidth=width;
        textHeight=height;
        VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.FOCUSABLE);   
        basicEditField=new EditField(null,null,200, Field.EDITABLE|Field.FOCUSABLE|BasicEditField.NO_NEWLINE);

        basicEditField.setFocusListener(this);
        vfm.add(basicEditField);
        add(vfm);
    }


    protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

        if(textWidth==0)
        {
            textWidth=maxWidth;
        }
        if(textHeight==0)
        {
            textHeight=maxHeight;
        }
        super.layout(textWidth, textHeight);
        setExtent(textWidth, textHeight);
    }


    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        graphics.drawRect(basicEditField.getLeft(),basicEditField.getTop(), textWidth, textHeight);

    }



    public void setHeight(int height) {
        textHeight= height;
    }


    public void setWidth(int width) {
        textWidth= width;
    }



    public Font getFont() {
        return font;
    }



    public void setFont(Font font) {
        this.font = font;
    }


    public void focusChanged(Field field, int eventType) {
        if(eventType==FOCUS_GAINED)
        {
            if(field==basicEditField)
            {
                basicEditField.setCursorPosition(basicEditField.getText().length());
            }
        }

    }


}
```

The typed thing doesn't get visible on the Screen
I have just created a CustomTextField which extends VerticalFieldManager
inside it 
I have added an EditField which gets added in VerticalFieldManager

But it does'nt work 
I mean it doesn't show what i type on the screen
What's the error can you check it out

I do invoke the CustomTextField using

```
CustomTextField ctf=new CustomTextField(100,200):
```

Comment: take a look at it http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/TextBoxField-revisited/ta-p/548410

Answer (score 1):

check

```
protected void paint(Graphics graphics)
```

add

```
super.paint(g);
```

at the end in it.